# Strange phenomenon when recording video with AVCaptureVideoDataOutput during the first video recording

Tags: ios, swift, video-capture, avcapturedevice, avcapturevideodataoutput

I use `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` to capture video with `setSampleBufferDelegate` function:

```
isRecoding = true
videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(videoCaptureAssign, queue: videoQueue)
audioOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(videoCaptureAssign, queue: videoQueue)
```

I get writeable data using function:

```
func writeBufferVideoToFile(assetWriter: AVAssetWriter,
                            sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) {
    guard isRecoding else {
        return
    }
    // Start record
    if assetWriter.status == .unknown {
        assetWriter.startWriting()
        assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer))
    }
    
    // Record data
    if let assetWriterInput = assetWriter.videoInput,
       assetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
        // Record
        assetWriterInput.append(sampleBuffer)
    }
}
```

Before recording video with `isRecoding = true`, I set:

```
device.torchMode = .on
```

However, the first time I record a video, `device.torchMode` will automatically switch to `.off` and the screen will go dark for about 0.2 seconds. This no longer happens the next time the video is recorded.

How to make sure that the first time you record a video, touchMode doesn't automatically turn off and the screen doesn't go so dark. Can anyone give me a suggestion to solve this problem?